# Disable Save & Save As option in all Browsers using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable Save As and Save options in all browsers (like Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc). I have already disabled right click on my web page.
The code is here:

```
    var message="Function Disabled!"; 
     function clickIE4()
       if(event.button==2){
          alert(message);
          return false; 
       }
    } 
    function clickNS4(e){
      if(document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
        if (e.which==2||e.which==3){  
          alert(message);
          return false; 
        } 
     } 
   } 
   if (document.layers){  
     document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
     document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
   } 
   else if(document.all&&!document.getElementById){
       document.onmousedown=clickIE4; 
   }  
   document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

Comment: Cannot be bothered trying to read that code.  It's messy!

Comment: you can always change or disable the context menu using javascript, if you don't know what a context menu is it is the menu that pops up when right clicking, also you can change what crt + s does, aka make it do nothing. here is a site that goes into changing the context menu http://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/ , and here is a site explaining how to change keyboard input https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

> I want to disable save as and save options in all Browsers,

You can't.

> i have already disable right click

Not very effectively.

---

DRM doesn't work well in systems that are designed to support it (e.g. DVD players). It is much less effective in systems that are not designed to support it (e.g. web browsers).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Answer (score 3):

By opening your webpage the user has already downloaded it - it is impossible to make a webpage that can be viewed, but not saved.

Of course, you can block some methods, as you have - you can even use some complex ajax or flash to really screw with them. But in the end there will always be a way around it. I suggest you look for a different approach to keeping your data where you want it. For example, if the issue is that people are "stealing" your images, you could watermark them.